Firestore API failed to connect crashing my app
Every time I switch from mock Data to real data from my Firebase, my app crashes:

As soon as I change this 3 lines of code my app crashes
Main Code
import SwiftUI

struct InboxView: View {
    
    @State private var showNewMessageView = false
//    @StateObject var viewModel = InboxViewModel() // uncomment this
    @State private var user = User.MOCK_USER // comment out this
    
//    private var user: User? { //uncomment this
//        return viewModel.currentUser
//    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                ActiveNowView()
                
                List {
                    ForEach(0 ... 10, id: \.self) { message in
                        InboxRowView()
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 120)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { user in
                ProfileView(user: user)
            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showNewMessageView, content: {
                NewMessageView()
            })
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(value: user) {
                            CircularProfileImageView(user: user, size: .xsmall)
                        }
                        
                        Text("Chats")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        showNewMessageView.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                            .foregroundStyle(.black, Color(.systemGray5))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

InboxViewModel
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase

class InboxViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    private var cancellabels = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        setupSuscribers()
    }
    
    private func setupSuscribers() {
        UserService.shared.$currentUser.sink { [weak self] user in
            self?.currentUser = user
        }.store(in: &cancellabels)
    }
}

User
import FirebaseFirestore
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var uid: String?

    let fullname: String
    let email: String
    let profileImageUrl: String?
    
    var id: String {
        return uid ?? NSUUID().uuidString
    }
}

extension User {
    static let MOCK_USER = User(fullname: "Bruce Wayne", email: "batman@gmail.com", profileImageUrl: "batman")
}

Authorisation Service
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class AuthService {
    
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    
    static let shared = AuthService()
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        loadCurrentUserData()
        print("User session id is \(userSession?.uid)")
    }
    
    @MainActor
    // Log in
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            loadCurrentUserData()
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to sign in user with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    // Sign in
    func createUser(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            try await self.uploadUserData(email: email, fullname: fullname, id: result.user.uid)
            loadCurrentUserData()
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to create user with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // Log out
    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut() // signs out on backend
            self.userSession = nil // update routing logic
            UserService.shared.currentUser = nil
        }   catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to sign out with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    
    // Data upload
    private func uploadUserData(email: String, fullname: String, id: String) async throws {
        let user = User(fullname: fullname, email: email, profileImageUrl: nil)
        guard let encodeUser = try? Firestore.Encoder().encode(user) else { return }
        try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(id).setData(encodeUser)
    }
    
    
    // bug fix (user details)
    private func loadCurrentUserData() {
        Task { try await UserService.shared.fetchCurrentUser() }
    }
}

The Terminal throws this error as soon as I run my code

I0000 00:00:1732088994.725995 1362774 subchannel.cc:806] subchannel 0x101c70a80 {address=ipv6:%5B2404:6800:4002:81a::200a%5D:443, args={grpc.client_channel_factory=0x60000002b3e0, grpc.default_authority=firestore.googleapis.com, grpc.http2_scheme=https, grpc.internal.channel_credentials=0x60000263cb40, grpc.internal.client_channel_call_destination=0x103d64828, grpc.internal.event_engine=0x60000002b4e0, grpc.internal.security_connector=0x600002c2d900, grpc.internal.subchannel_pool=0x600002949500, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=30000, grpc.primary_user_agent=grpc-c++/1.65.1, grpc.resource_quota=0x600000c99680, grpc.server_uri=dns:///firestore.googleapis.com}}: connect failed (UNKNOWN:(domain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code:50, description:The operation couldn’t be completed. Network is down) {file:"/var/folders/hn/5bx1f4_d4ds5vhwhkxc7vdcr0000gn/T/ZipRelease/2024-07-25T04-01-28/project-ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc", file_line:150, created_time:"2024-11-20T13:19:54.724606+05:30", grpc_status:2}), backing off for 874 ms
DEBUG: Current user is Optional(Messenger.User(_uid: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentID<Swift.String>(value: Optional("Tg2TbvUlWBdjtL1XKkFJD6MeGKn1")), fullname: "Bruce Wayne", email: "batman@gmail.com", profileImageUrl: nil))


"Network is down", have you enabled network access for your app? (Signing & Capabilities -> App Sandbox -> Incoming/Outgoing connections)

It's already enabled.

The app crashes when switching from mock data to real Firebase data. The terminal log includes a Network is down error and shows that the profileImageUrl is nil, leading to a crash when rendering the profile image.
Update the User Code :
var safeProfileImageUrl: String {
    return profileImageUrl ?? "defaultImageURL"
}

When switching from mock data to real data, the InboxViewModel is responsible for fetching and observing the real user data. If the currentUser is nil, your app may crash when trying to access properties like profileImageUrl.

It didn't solve the issue. I am adding my Authorisation Service code in the question please take a look at it, if it might help
